# CSS single-line layout with flexible width (tricky)

Tags: css, layout

I'd like to make a single-line CSS layout which flows to the right indefinitely. 
Each box would have a certain percentage (e.g. 20%) of the viewport width.

This is much easier to explain with a picture:

```
+-----------------------------+
|VIEWPORT                     |
|                             |
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ 
|BOX| |BOX| |...| |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | 
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ 
|           |<--->|           |          
|   20% of the viewport width |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

*Why would I want to do this?*

I have a site which displays a calendar (as a grid, http://www.airdates.tv/) and I'd like to offer an alternate view.  There would be seven boxes visible (the current day being in the middle). I'd use javascript to offer left/right buttons that scroll exactly one box to the left/right. Of course, I could do the box sizing with JavaScript too, but I'd very much prefer a CSS solution.

*What's my problem?*

I know it can easily be done with javascript, but in css i can't wrap my around how to specify sizes in terms of the viewport width (opposed to terms of the parent container width). I welcome any kinds of vague thoughts, suggestions or snippets.

Comment: What's the question?  Or is this just a _"give me the code"_ post?

Comment: lol, yes, pretty much. not because i'm lazy, but i'm open to any kind of answer. i'll add details to the question to make this more clear in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VWJtk/5/) could be done without the outer wrapper, but I figure you are going to want other things on the page, so will probably want to isolate it.

It uses `inline-block` to get the horizontal flow.

Comment: Just a quick note, :last-child doesn't play well with IE (or rather IE doesn't play well with everything else).  It is better to use :first-child instead as there is partial support for it. In this case switch the margin-right to margin-left and change to :first-child.

Comment: oooh.... combining no-wrap and inline block... i don't think i would have guessed that. thanks, that does exactly what i want! i tested with all browsers available on browserstack, works for ie8+, ff3+, safari4+,chrome14+.

Comment: @kritzikratzi--glad it meets your needs. Also, thanks for the info from browserstack--I didn't even know such a site existed, that knowledge could prove useful.

Comment: yep, it's a crazy handy site... everyone should know about it :)

Answer (score 0):

ok so I can't promise that it extends indefinitely to the right but it is very close, and be scaled to fit.  I truly believe this is as close as you can get.  This particular example will easily hold up to 2500 entries.  You need to add a inside 'frame' to control the flow of the floats and to help hide it from view.  Here is the sample that I put together for you: http://jsfiddle.net/e68dh/16/

NOTE: there are some rounding errors for display when #outside is give 'ugly' widths, but this should be easy to tweak.

Comment: i see where this is going, this should work in all browsers which is an advantage, but the rounding errors are scaring me away from doing this (especially because my boxes width is something like 14.25%)

Comment: Sorry I should not have accredited the browser with the fault, the rounding errors are directly result of the accuracy of your calculations. In this case I used .009% but I sure that it could be adjusted if more precise numbers were used. It is possible to get a clean edge by just error on the side of letting the 'next' box sit outside the area instead of cleanly aligning with the edge.